# Large String to Array in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

Background:
I "downloading" a CSV via we .NET webclient call.

```
$url="https://host.domain.ext/site/folder/file?format=csv"
$username="USERNAME"
$password="PASSWORD"

$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)
$webpage = $webclient.DownloadString($url)
```

After the above, $webpage is a System.Sting. String? Huh? That's odd... ok so how can I get that to be an array so that I can parse it correctly like I would a CSV that I imported.

Things I've tried that haven't work...

```
$webpage | convertto-csv
$webpage | Export-csv $path
import-csv $webpage
```

Things I have tried that work but are messy...

```
$webpage >> $path
import-csv $path
```

PS
Yes the file has commas as deliminator.

Comment: Can you post the content of $webpage ? I recommend you specify the encoding when you write the file.  Export-Csv has "-Encoding" parameter.

Comment: If you have CSV string and want to have objects, than you have to use `ConvertFrom-Csv` not `ConvertTo-Csv`.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. :-)

@Sylvain: I cannot, it is confidential info. What I can say is that if I were to download the file from a browser it would be a properly formatted CSV and that if I pipe the text into a file and then Import the file it is a properly formatted CSV/array.

Comment: @PetSerAl nailed it. Thank you!

$array=($webpage | ConvertFrom-Csv)

Comment: @AaronWurthmann BTW why were you surprised that a method called `DownloadString()` gave you back a `string`?  :-)

Comment: @AaronWurthmann: You don't need parentheses around the pipeline in your last comment's code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can download it as a file, this solution is not making sense on the technical point of view, but it's completly obvious on the IT point of view.

```
$webclient.DownloadFile($uri, "c:\temp\tempfile")
```

If you don't want to download it you can split your string to an array on carriage return `` `r `` or carriage return line feed `` `r`n ``.

```
$url="http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv"
$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient

# Split your string with `r  or `r`n
$webpage = $webclient.DownloadString($url)
$webpage.Split("`r") | ConvertFrom-Csv

# Download a file
$webclient.DownloadFile($url,"d:\temp\Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv")
Import-Csv "d:\temp\Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv"
```

Comment: No need to download as a file if all you do is reading it in afterwards again. And why split on lines when you pass it to `ConvertFrom-Csv`? All of that makes little to no sense here.

Comment: @Joey, just test my code, in the case the CSV file contains `r and not `r`n, if you omit the split it won't work. It's better to test before downvote.

Comment: Can't redact it by now. Writing to a file is still nonsense and unnecessary, though. And valid CSV should never have CR as line separator (as per the RFC).

Comment: @Joey, sometime things which are non sense on the technical point of view are just obvious on the IT point of view. When you manage every day thousands of lines of data flow you prefer separe the problems, first download, then process the data.